# RESTful API and SOAP service

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, soa, esb

### I am learning SOAP and I have some questions:

1. If I have a **SOAP** service, and if my understanding is correct then the consumer will need to import the WSDL and generate the stubs to consume my service?
2. If now I have exposed the **SOAP** service with a **RESTful** API with the help of a **ESB** in between. Does that mean the consumer no longer need to import any WSDL to generate the stubs?

Comment: Yes, you will need a exposed wsdl to consume and generate stubs.

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne Do you mean the consumers still need to find the wsdl and generate the stubs in case#2 where I have a RESTful API for the service?

Comment: my reply was for #1, however for second case as far as for my knowledge in RESTful API one don't need a WSDL. Only the URL of REST service will be needed by the consumer. It now depends on your REST service how it communicates with SOAP service via ESB.

Comment: According to me WSDL will now be needed by either ESB or REST service instead of consumer. Because consumer will be using interacting with REST service through a url.                                                                                       (consumer -> REST(via URL) -> ESB -> SOAP(via WSDL)).

Comment: On your #2, REST doesn't get stubs generated. You have to code REST calls by hand. If you want stubs generated, then stick with SOAP.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for your comment. So, you mean even I make my SOAP web services as APIs, the callers of these APIs still need to generate the stubs? If so, whats the point of having SOAP APIs rather leaving them as services?

Comment: You seem to have some confusion. Having stubs is a _good thing_. It means that the code necessary to call the service is generated for you - you don't have to write it yourself. In the case of REST services, the service does not provide the metadata which would be required to generate the stubs, so the developer has to read the documentation and create his own "stubs", or else just write inline code.

Comment: Of course, if your client is in a language which has no tool support for generating stubs for a SOAP service (JavaScript, for instance), then you would have to write the code to call the SOAP service on your own. It can be much more complicated to write the code to call a SOAP service than to write the code to call a REST service. That's one reason why REST is preferred for languages like JavaScript.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for clearing my confusion. I thought stubs was a bad (at least troublesome) thing because it gives you a skeleton and the consumer will need to implement the details themselves. But now thinking about that, they are just implementing the clients and call the generated services only. They are not implementing the service itself! Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes -the idea behind SOAP specification (wsdl) is so that clients can use it to  create a proxy for calling the service and not have to figure out the details for themselves. It is very hard to connect to a SOAP service without using a wsdl
2. In this case the ESB does the calls to the actual service and the REST interface is a new interface client should use to communicate with the service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It gives me some confidence that what I am thinking is correct. But would mind telling me what's the difference between a SOAP API and SOAP service? I think the way to consume both is the same (import wsdl, generate stubs etc.)

Comment: SOAP API is the endpoints of the service represented by the  WSDL of the SOAP based service

Comment: @xcoder a SOAP API is normally a collection of one or more SOAP  services. So yes you would consume a SOAP API by consuming the services that make up the API.

Comment: @Namphibian Thanks for your comment. "A collection of services"... do you mean if a SOAP API has 2 services, I would fist need to import 2 wsdls and generate the stubs, then call the relevant operations?

Comment: @xcoder it might be one wsdl or 100 wsdl files. You would only generate code for the parts of the api u consume.  A wsdl might cover some or all of the api. Typically you will have a catalog of services aka wsdl files that you can pick and choose from.

Comment: @Namphibian aha a catalog! Thanks for the explanation!